# Can you manually populate Address long/lat fields

Tags: data-loader, address

I use Billing Address in my Salesforce org with Data integrations turned on so that Salesforce can populate the `BillingLongitude` and `BillingLatitude`.

Some of my addresses aren't being populated and wondered whether its possible to manually populate them using Data Loader? If yes, are there any considerations I need to take manually altering this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to populate these fields using dataloader.

Comment: Can you turn this into the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to populate these fields using dataloader.